# Converting code from my .aspx page to code behind in the C# .cs page

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

Learning how to code in ASP.NET via Visual Studio comes with its pros and cons. The pros are that everything is so easy to do via drag and drop, but the con is that I don't know much about the code behind and all of this "data binding". I have this code in my .aspx page, but I'm not sure how to "convert" it to the code behind. For example, I am right now attempting to implement an application that is in essence a searchable (that has a drop down list to serve as a filter on which column to search on) Gridview with paging that has read and write capabilities. Here is the code I have thus far in my .aspx page:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        .hiddencol 
        { 
            display: none; 
        }
     </style>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="SearchBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="SearchParameterList" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="Project_Name">Project Name</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Product">Product</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Description">Description</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:Button ID="SearchButton" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="SearchButton_Click" />
    <asp:Button ID="ClearButton" runat="server" OnClick="ClearButton_Click" Text="Clear" />
    <br />
    <br />

    <asp:GridView ID="ProjectTable" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana,Arial" Font-Size="12px" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" DataSourceID="PopulateProjectTable" AllowPaging="True" OnPageIndexChanging="ProjectTable_PageIndexChanging>
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#BFE4FF" />
        <PagerStyle BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" />
        <HeaderStyle Height="30px" BackColor="#6DC2FF" Font-Size="12px" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" />
        <RowStyle Height="20px" Font-Size="12px" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ProjID" HeaderText="ProjID" ItemStyle-CssClass="hiddencol" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hiddencol" SortExpression="ProjID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Project_Name" HeaderText="Project Name Value" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Project_Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Product" HeaderText="Product" SortExpression="Product" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Product_Edit" HeaderText="Product (alternate)" SortExpression="Product_Edit" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Description" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Description_Edit" HeaderText="Description (alternate)" SortExpression="Description_Edit" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Comment" HeaderText="Comment Submission/Approval" SortExpression="Comment" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="PopulateProjectTable" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ODSConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [Project_Name], [Product], [Product_Edit], [Description], [Description_Edit], [Comment], [ProjID] FROM [Pipeline_Detail]" 
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Pipeline_Detail] SET Product_Edit = @Product_Edit, Description_Edit= @Description_Edit, Comment = @Comment WHERE ProjID = @ProjID">
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="ProjID"/>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Product_Edit" Type="String"/>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Description_Edit" Type="String"/>        
            <asp:Parameter Name="Comment" Type="String"/>
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>

</div>
</form>
```

And here is what I have in the code behind:

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PopulateProjectTable.FilterExpression = SearchParameterList.SelectedValue.ToString() + " LIKE " + "'" + "%{0}%" + "'";
    }

    protected void ClearButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PopulateProjectTable.FilterExpression = "Project_Name LIKE '%%'";
        SearchBox.Text = "";
    }
}
```

Very barren. The issue I'm running into right now is that the paging "resets" itself after I search. For example, if I search up something that can't be displayed in one page, it'll obviously page it. If I click on any/all pages that isn't Page 1, the gridview resets back to its original select statement and shows what would be page 2 of THAT. I did some research and I see that it is an issue with the way the data is bound (feel free to correct me if that isn't the issue here). As such, how can I remedy the problem I'm having right now, and will it require me to convert my .aspx page to code behind in C#?

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: I made a big change with my code behind:

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ProjectTable.PageIndex = 0;
        ProjectTable.DataSourceID = null;
        PopulateProjectTable.SelectCommand = "SELECT [Project_Name], [Product], [Product_Edit], [Description], [Description_Edit], [Comment], [ProjID] FROM [Pipeline_Detail] WHERE " + SearchParameterList.SelectedValue.ToString() + " LIKE '%" + SearchBox.Text + "%'";
        ProjectTable.DataSource = PopulateProjectTable;
        ProjectTable.DataBind();
    }

    protected void ClearButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ProjectTable.PageIndex = 0;
        ProjectTable.DataSourceID = null;
        PopulateProjectTable.SelectCommand = "SELECT [Project_Name], [Product], [Product_Edit], [Description], [Description_Edit], [Comment], [ProjID] FROM [Pipeline_Detail] WHERE Project_Name LIKE '%%'";
        ProjectTable.DataSource = PopulateProjectTable;
        ProjectTable.DataBind();
        SearchBox.Text = "";
    }

    protected void ProjectTable_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        ProjectTable.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        ProjectTable.DataSourceID = null;
        PopulateProjectTable.SelectCommand = "SELECT [Project_Name], [Product], [Product_Edit], [Description], [Description_Edit], [Comment], [ProjID] FROM [Pipeline_Detail] WHERE " + SearchParameterList.SelectedValue.ToString() + " LIKE '%" + SearchBox.Text + "%'" ;
        ProjectTable.DataSource = PopulateProjectTable; 
        ProjectTable.DataBind();

    }
}
```

I'm now getting these type of errors:

```
The GridView 'ProjectTable' fired event RowEditing which wasn't handled.
The GridView 'ProjectTable' fired event RowCancelingEdit which wasn't handled.
```

Anyone know what's up?

Comment: Upvote because you've clearly got your wits about you. If this is not answered by the time I leave work this evening, I'll take a stab at it. I do think your question may be too broad to give a simple answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the support. Never took classes for it so everything was self-taught. There's only so much I can learn on my own.

Comment: Since you appear to be eager to learn and in the beginning of your learning process, you might want to abandon Web Forms altogether, as it's clearly not with where the industry is moving. Learn ASP.NET MVC instead.

Comment: Interesting, I'll check it out. Though, I want to finish this first.

Comment: @mason Webforms aren't going anywhere.

Comment: @JohnPaul Web Forms is tied to System.Web. Neither System.Web nor Web Forms have made it into the new architecture, but MVC and Web Pages has. And they have made no announcements regarding Web Forms being added. I think it's safe to assume that either Microsoft doesn't see value in adding Web Forms to the new architecture, or they place a much lower priority on it than MVC. If you have information that states otherwise, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/04/30/updates-for-asp-net-4-6-web-forms-mvc-5-web-api-2.aspx

Comment: @JohnPaul That's ASP.NET 4.6. That's not ASP.NET 5. Web Forms is not in ASP.NET 5, which is the future of ASP.NET. That quite clearly shows that Microsoft either does not plan to add it at all, or that they consider it a much lower priority than MVC, such a low priority that it's not even on the [roadmap](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Roadmap).

Comment: Those are two separate branches of .NET and are both going to be developed and maintained in parallel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix the paging issue you need to rebind the data on every page index change. The issue with your markup is although you have AllowPaging set to true you never implemented the on page index changing event thus the data gets "lost" when the page index changes. Here is example markup and code behind. Please let me know if you need further clarification.

MarkUp:

```
<asp:GridView ID="ProjectTable" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana,Arial" Font-Size="12px" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" DataSourceID="PopulateProjectTable" AllowPaging="True" OnPageIndexChaning="ProjectTable_PageIndexChanging">
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void ProjectTable_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    //Set the page index
    this.ProjectTable_PageIndexChanging.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;

    //Rebind the data
    this.ProjectTable_PageIndexChanging.DataSource = PopulateProjectTable;
    this.ProjectTable_PageIndexChanging.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Do I need to change the code for my Page_Load as well? As for the GetDataSource() method, how should it look like?

Comment: Page_Load should be fine. It looks like you are using a SqlDataSource as the data source so you can just set the data source to that. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Actually, would this work? Since I have a search box, wouldn't this just set the data back to what is to be page 2 without the results from the search box?

Comment: Then you would just set it to the same data the search results came with. For example set the filter expression again before data binding.

Comment: Thanks, you pointed me in the right direction. You had typos in your aspx page and the code behind which slightly threw me off. I edited the main post with some interesting errors that I didn't have before. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Set a breakpoint in your Page_Load event.

When you click on page 2, you need to rebind the data to your grid. It usually involves something like this:

```
if(Page.IsPostBack) { 
  ProjectTable.DataSource = [some collection which populates your grid]
  ProjectTable.DataBind();
}
```